# Open and close modal dialog in same function

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a site that populates data into a table when it loads.  Each column header is clickable resulting in the table sorting based on that column's data.  This works fine, but it is slow so i was hoping to have a modal window popup advising the end user to wait while it sorts.  I have the code for the modal window already made as well as the javascript line to call it and close it, but I cannot get it to appear and then disappear when the sort is done.

Modal Code:

```
<div id="SortingBox" class="modal3">        
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content3">
        <div class="modal-header2">
            <h2>Loading</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body2">
            <pre><strong style="color: black;">Please Wait...</strong></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I call the modal with this line:

```
document.getElementById('SortingBox').style.display='block';
```

And close it with this:

```
document.getElementById('SortingBox').style.display='none';
```

Now I already have this working on page load and the line to close it is at the end of the sorting script in a separate js file.  So all I want it to be able to have it appear when a column header is clicked and close again after the sort is complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use classList's `toggle` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods)?

Create a class that called `is-modal-hidden`, with `display: none`.

```
// style.css
.is-modal-hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

Create a js function to toggle modal, by toggling the class.

Something like that:

```
function toggleModal() {
   document.getElementById('SortingBox').classList.toggle('is-modal-hidden');
}
```

Comment: I apologize as I'm very new to js programming.  I like what you are suggesting, but when you say "with display: none" what do you mean specifically?

Comment: Create a css file that loads with the html, there put css selector with the name, and declaration with what I mentioned...

Comment: The CSS is in place, but it reports that the object doesn't support toggleClass.

Comment: My bad, it suppose to be just `toggle`

Comment: This has solved that issue, but the function call does not seem to be working.  I've placed it in the onClick as well as directly in the main sorting function in my js file, but no luck.

Comment: Ok I now know why my modal was not showing...it actually was, but because the GUI was not refreshing until the sorting function was finished it was closing the modal before it refreshed.  So my issue to overcome now is, how can I have the header upon first click load the modal and carry on with the functions code and then once complete then close it.